# C# class within a class (or nesting)

Tags: c#, class, reporting-services

Hey all I have made the following class:

```
public class ssrsFormats
{
    public static readonly string
    pdf = "PDF",
    mhtml = "MHTML",
    html4 = "HTML4.0",
    html3 = "HTML3.2",
    excel1 = "EXCELOPENXML",
    excel2 = "EXCEL",
    word1 = "WORDOPENXML",
    word2 = "WORD",
    csv = "CSV",
    xml = "XML",
    image = "IMAGE";
}
```

And what I am wondering is how (if) I can do something like so:

```
ssrsFormats.image.jpeg
```

I only want to do this so I have a type of **"intellisense"** in order to help me build the function call when it comes to that.

Instead of me trying to remember the image formats within the SSRS formats class, I start typing **ssrsformats.image.** and it pops up the image formats for me to pick from.

I am trying to also do this **within one class** instead of having multiple classes that point to other classes.

Comment: What about an `enum`? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Not sure @AlphaDelta. Happen to show an example of how that would look?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This definitely sounds like it should be enums, preferrably following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: The title of your question says that you know how to do it -- make a nested class. However, I would encourage you to not do this; public nested classes are considered a bit of a bad code smell in .NET. The standard way to do this would be to make several classes which use each other, but you have rejected the standard practice for no given reason. Without knowing why you have rejected the standard good advice it's hard to give you additional good advice.

Comment: @EricLippert Slightly related, but would you consider [something like this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/294d588e4d9098f0b9574f85709c0498a35c5aa7/src/IdentityServer4/IdentityServerConstants.cs) to be a code smell too? On the face of it, it looks like a handy way to hierarchically organise string consts.

Comment: Completely disregard the comment I just deleted with a use-case, I forgot enums have to be integral. DavidG raises a good point, as long as it makes it easier to mantain and it's easy for someone to understand your code it should be fine; nested classes seem like a good enough solution.

Comment: @DavidG: My question were I asked to review that code would be "what does hierarchical organization buy you in this case?"  I would just make all those classes top-level static classes. **What is the compelling value of forcing the developer to type `IdentityServerConstants` all over the place?**  `IdentityServer4.ProtocolTypes.WsFederation` is perfectly clear. `IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ProtocolTypes.WsFederation` has an additional level of hierarchy that is completely useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should have two classes and enums, one class for the more general part (is the document some text or image-format), and one for the more detailed file-format (Word, PDF, JPEG, ...).

```
class TextDocument
{
    public TextFormats TheFormat { get; set; }
    public enum TextFormats 
    {
        Word, Pdf, ...
    }
}

class ImageDocument
{
    public ImageFormats TheFormat { get; set; }
    public enum ImageFormats
    {
        JPEG, TIF, BMP, ...
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var image = new ImageDocument { TheFormat = ImageDocument.ImageFormats.JPEG };
```

and

```
var doc = new TextDocument { TheFormat = TextDocument.FileFormats.Word };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static class ssrsFormats
{
  public static class Image
  {
     public const string Jpeg=".jpg";
  }
}
```